Copying between two different workbooks with VBA
I got a code to copy data from a closed workbook to another active workbook but I have a probelm in closing workbooks after runing the code I don't know how to fix it
my source Workbook is "Stop Work" sheet1 and the destination workbook is "AUTHS" and sheet name is "stop work" the code run smoothly but my probelm is that after runnig the code and copying the data my active workbook which I'm working on it "AUTHS" get closed and the source workbook which was closed get opened  while i need the vice versa (to save and close "stop Work" and keep "AUTHS" open - I Have tried changing true and false but nothing done
this is my code
Sub mycode()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Desktop\Stop Work.xlsm"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Desktop\AUTHs.xlsm"
Worksheets("Stop Work").Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll             'xlPasteAll to paste everything
ActiveWorkbook.Save

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False        'to close the file
Workbooks("D:\Desktop\Stop Work.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True  'to close the file

End Sub



thank you in advance        


Cannot define the range because it a table - The range of your table will be Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table Name").Range or if only one table Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).Range

Copy from Closed Workbook
Sub CopyFromClosedWorkbook()
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Desktop\Stop Work.xlsm")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range:
    With sws.UsedRange
        Set srg = sws.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Stop Work")
    Dim dfcell As Range
    ' Either overwrite...
    dws.UsedRange.Clear ' clear existing data
    Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
    ' ... or append:
    'With dws.UsedRange
    '    Set dfcell = .Cells(1).EntireRow.Columns("A").Offset(.Rows.Count)
    'End With
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Either copy values, formulas and formatting...
    srg.Copy Destination:=drg
    ' ... or copy only values:
    'drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Close the source workbook.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just read from
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    dwb.Save
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub


thank you so much you also gave me another option to paste only values - I appreciate your help - it works

please let me know is there a way to copy values+ cell formatting like boarders and colors ? - I mean everything except formulas - is that possible?

Simply uncomment and replace the 2nd line of code, i.e., drg.Value = srg.Value, with drg.Value = drg.Value which will overwrite the (copied) formulas with values.

yes I have tried that before asking you but it gave me just bulk of text no boarders and no formatting like cell size and color

You need both lines, i.e., keep srg.Copy Destination:=drg also.

Great, thank you so much - just one last issue - can we add a rule to remove any filter in the source file before copying because it crashes if the source file was closed with filters

If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData.

Great, thank you so much for your help and being pateint

Better to use variables to identify the workbooks.  Something like below
' Open the source workbook  
Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\Desktop\Stop Work.xlsm")  

sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy  

' Open the destination workbook  
Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\Desktop\AUTHs.xlsm")  
 
destinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Stop Work").Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll  

destinationWorkbook.Save  

' Close the source workbook after saving changes  
sourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False


thanks alot for your help.  it's working but with two issue - 1- I got boarder lines in the blank rows underneath the table in destination file which don't exist in the source file...  and 2- it take s a while to save the destination file - any suggesstion please?

You can Define the range to copy like
Set sourceRange = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10") ' Change the range as needed
Define the destination range
Set destinationRange = destinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Stop Work").Range("A1")
Then copy the range and paste it
sourceRange.Copy
destinationRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

honestly after running the code some times it run smoothly now and without extra boarders - thank you so much for your help

Cannot define the range because it a table with new data added from day to day and subject to new rows  - thanks any way

Sounds good.  If you were to implement range copy then you can find out the last non empty row using
"rowCount = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(tDataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row"
and use it to define the source range. This way we can find out the last filled row and copy accordingly.

and where to add this line in the code - it could accelerate the run I think = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(tDataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row"
